# Should I edit this question or make a new question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, asking-questions

[Should the Grothendieck ring of varieties be K_0 of numerical motives?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200113/should-the-grothendieck-ring-of-varieties-be-k-0-of-numerical-motives)

I want to change it to:

1) Asking about after tensoring with $\Qb$

2) Asking if there is a map in some direction and if anything can be said about this map

Should I edit it or make a new question?

Comment: What did you want to tensor it with? $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 9):

Since your old question has two upvoted answers, I would recommend not to edit it.
If you did, the good answers would become non-answers (or only partial answers), which can make the answerers unwilling to answer you again.
Also, people that want to find an answer to your old question (which was of interest to some people judging by upvotes) will have harder time finding it if you edit drastically.
Ask a new question instead, and provide a link.